# Anyone vs someone

Tags: pronouns, indefinite-pronouns

If **anyone** could teach me how to play the guitar, I'd much appreciate it.

If **someone** could teach me how to play the guitar, I'd much appreciate it.

Do both the sentences mean the same thing, or do they mean different things according to which pronoun, anyone or someone, you choose to use?

Comment: In this context they mean the same thing.  In a different context, they would mean different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between *anyone* and *someone* **is** very ambiguous.

Some of the differences are:

1. Anyone is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf).
2. "Someone" implies we are looking for more than one while "Anyone" implies, we are wondering if even one exists that meets the criteria.
3. "Some" is generally replaced by "Any" in negative and interrogative contexts. But it is not as simple as that: "Some" **can** be used in interrogative contexts

E.g.

> Does Sarah have some money?
>
> Who has some money?

However, in your example, both can be used interchangeably